# jqueryUI draggable droppable and item from array problem

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I have the following problem:

when I take a card and put it ,I find and place the right one for the first time in the index, but the second time I put it right, but then both do it according to the last one etc.

Here the code works for me,and it probably doesn't work here:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("body").append("<div id='top' </div>");
  $("#top").append("<h1> <b>BLACK JACK</b> </h1>");
  $("body").append("<div id='buttons' </div>");
  $("body").append("<div id='index'> </div>");
  $("body").append("<div id='gameDesk' </div>");
  $("body").append("<div id='cardsDesk' </div>");
  $("#buttons").append(
    "<button type='button'  id='startGame' class='btn btn-secondary'>Start game</button>"
  );

  const SuitValue = [
    (suit = ["S", "C", "D", "H"]),
    (value = [
      "2",
      "3",
      "4",
      "5",
      "6",
      "7",
      "8",
      "9",
      "10",
      "10J",
      "10Q",
      "10K",
      "11A",
    ]),
  ];

  var cardsArray = [];
  var shuffleCards = [];
  var playerCards = [];

  for (let i = 0; i < value.length; i++) {
    for (let j = 0; j < suit.length; j++) {
      cardsArray.push(value[i] + suit[j]);
    }
  }

  function shuffle(array) {
    var currentIndex = array.length,
      temporaryValue,
      randomIndex;

    // While there remain elements to shuffle...
    while (0 !== currentIndex) {
      // Pick a remaining element...
      randomIndex = Math.floor(Math.random() * currentIndex);
      currentIndex -= 1;

      // And swap it with the current element.
      temporaryValue = array[currentIndex];
      array[currentIndex] = array[randomIndex];
      array[randomIndex] = temporaryValue;
    }

    return array;
  }
  $("#startGame").click(function() {
    $("#buttons").html(
      "<button type='button'  id='shuffleCards' class='btn btn-secondary'>mix cards</button>"
    );
    $("#index").html(
      "<h5>" + "on the table " + cardsArray.length + " cards" + "</h4>"
    );
    for (let i = 0; i < cardsArray.length; i++) {
      var cards = cardsArray[i];
      $("#cardsDesk").append(`<img  src="assets/img/cards/${cards}.png" />`);
    }

    $("#shuffleCards").click(function() {
      $("#cardsDesk").remove();
      $("body").append("<div id='cardsDesk' </div>");

      shuffle(cardsArray);
      for (let i = 0; i < cardsArray.length; i++) {
        const element = cardsArray[i];
        $("#cardsDesk").append(
          `<img  src="assets/img/cards/card back black.png" />`
        );
      }
      console.log(cardsArray);

      $("#buttons").html(
        "<button type='button'  id='enough' class='btn btn-secondary'>Enough</button>"
      );

      $("#gameDesk").append("<span  class='slot' >drag card here</span>");

      dragDrop();

      function dragDrop() {
        $("img").draggable({
          cursor: "grab",
          revert: true,
          snap: ".slot",
          snapMode: "center",
          snapTolerance: "",
          stack: "img",
        });

        $(".slot").droppable({
          accept: "img",
          activeClass: "ui-state-default",
          hoverClass: "ui-state-hover",

          drop: function(event, ui) {
            $(".slot").droppable("option", "disabled", true);
            $("img").draggable("option", "destroy", true);
            $(this).find("img").html();

            $(ui.draggable).remove();
            var imgIndex = $(this).index();
            var src = cardsArray[imgIndex];
            $(".slot").html(
              `<img class="playerCard"  src="assets/img/cards/${src}.png" />`
            );
            $(".playerCard").draggable({
              disabled: true,
            });
            $("<span  class='slot' >drag card here</span>")
              .droppable()
              .appendTo("#gameDesk");

            console.log(src);
            return dragDrop();
          },
        });
      }
      $("#enough").click(function() {});
    });
  });
});
```

```css
html {
  -webkit-tap-highlight-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
}

body {
  background-color: darkgreen;
}

#top {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  background-color: darkgreen;
  text-align: center;
}

h1 {
  font-family: Georgia, "Times New Roman", Times, serif;
}

#buttons {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  background-color: darkgreen;
  text-align: center;
}

#index {
  background-color: darkgreen;
  text-align: center;
}

#gameDesk {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  align-items: flex-start;
  padding-left: 50px;
  padding-bottom: 20px;
  background-color: darkgreen;
}

.slot {
  margin-right: 40px;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  background-color: rgb(11, 126, 11);
  border-radius: 2px;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 1rem;
  font-weight: bold;
  width: 3rem;
}

#cardsDesk {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: flex-start;
  background-color: darkgreen;
  max-height: 39rem;
}

img {
  height: 7.3rem;
  width: 5rem;
}

.imgDrag {
  z-index: 1;
  opacity: 0.5;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<body>

</body>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/Lfd07y8e/

Comment: you do know you are attempting to append invalid HTML here right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not 100% sure what you are attempting but here I created some "player slots" and let you drag cards to them.

I found syntax issues all over and moved the HTML out of the script and into the markup, creating a "slot" that I could clone to put cards into.

I also put some namespace around this to hopefully make it easier to segregate your concerns here (objects and functions to call etc.)

```js
/* this is bad, moved to the HTML */
/*
  $("body").append("<div id='top"> </div>");
  $("#top").append("<h1> <b>BLACK JACK</b> </h1>");
  $("body").append("<div id='buttons'> </div>");
  $("body").append("<div id='index'> </div>");
  $("body").append("<div id='gameDesk'> </div>");
  $("body").append("<div id='cardsDesk'> </div>");
  
  $("#buttons").append(
    "<button type='button'  id='startGame' class='btn btn-secondary'>Start game</button>"
  );*/

// simple namespace all this and create descrete functions and values
var myGame = {
  SuitValue: {
    suit: ["S", "C", "D", "H"],
    value: ["2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10", "10J", "10Q", "10K", "11A"]
  },
  cardsArray: [],
  shuffleCards: [],
  playerCards: [],
  numberOfPlayers: 3,
  setup: function() {
    for (let i = 0; i < this.SuitValue.value.length; i++) {
      for (let j = 0; j < this.SuitValue.suit.length; j++) {
        this.cardsArray.push(this.SuitValue.value[i] + this.SuitValue.suit[j]);
      }
    }
  },
  shuffle: function(cards) {
    let currentIndex = cards.length,
      temporaryValue,
      randomIndex;
    // While there remain elements to shuffle...
    while (!!currentIndex) {
      // Pick a remaining element...
      randomIndex = Math.floor(Math.random() * currentIndex);
      currentIndex -= 1;
      // And swap it with the current element.
      temporaryValue = cards[currentIndex];
      cards[currentIndex] = cards[randomIndex];
      cards[randomIndex] = temporaryValue;
    }
    return cards;
  },
  placeCard: function(card) {
    $("#cardsDesk").append(`<img class="this-card" src="assets/img/cards/${card}.png" alt="${card}" />`);
  },
  startGame: function(event) {
    $("#shuffleCards").show();
    $("#index").html("<h5> on the table " + myGame.cardsArray.length + " cards</h4>");
    for (let i = 0; i < myGame.cardsArray.length; i++) {
      let card = myGame.cardsArray[i];
      myGame.placeCard(card);
    }
  },
  shuffleHandler: function(event) {
    // console.log("shuffle handle");
    let cardsDeck = $("#cardsDesk");
    let game = $("#gameDesk");
    cardsDeck.hide().empty();
    let cards = myGame.shuffle(myGame.cardsArray);
    for (let i = 0; i < cards.length; i++) {
      let card = cards[i];
      myGame.placeCard(card);
      // cardsDeck.append(`<img class="this-card" src="assets/img/cards/card back black.png" alt="$(cards[i])" />`);
    }
    cardsDeck.show();
    //console.log(myGame.cardsArray);
    $("#enough").show();
    let h = $('#hold-stuff').find(".slot.hidden").first();
    for (let p = 0; p < myGame.numberOfPlayers; p++) {
      let s = h.clone();
      game.append(s);
    }
    game.find(".slot.hidden").removeClass('hidden').addClass("player-slot");
    dragDrop();
  }
};

$(function() {
  $("#startGame").on('click', myGame.startGame);
  $("#shuffleCards").on("click", myGame.shuffleHandler);
  myGame.setup();
});

function dragDrop() {
  $("#cardsDesk")
    .find("img.this-card")
    .draggable({
      cursor: "grab",
      revert: true,
      snap: ".slot",
      snapMode: "center",
      snapTolerance: "",
      stack: "img",
    });
  $('#gameDesk')
    .find(".player-slot")
    .droppable({
      accept: ".this-card",
      activeClass: "ui-state-default",
      tolerance: "pointer",
      hoverClass: "ui-state-hover",
      drop: function(event, ui) {
        ui.draggable.detach().appendTo($(this));
      }
    });
}
$("#enough").on('click', function() {
  console.log("get out now");
});
```

```css
.hidden {
  display: none;
}

html {
  -webkit-tap-highlight-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
}

body {
  background-color: darkgreen;
}

#top {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  background-color: darkgreen;
  text-align: center;
}

h1 {
  font-family: Georgia, "Times New Roman", Times, serif;
}

#buttons {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  background-color: darkgreen;
  text-align: center;
}

#index {
  background-color: darkgreen;
  text-align: center;
}

#gameDesk {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  align-items: flex-start;
  padding-left: 50px;
  padding-bottom: 20px;
  background-color: darkgreen;
}

.slot {
  margin-right: 40px;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  background-color: 0b7e0b;
  border-radius: 2px;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 1rem;
  font-weight: bold;
  width: 3rem;
}

#cardsDesk {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: flex-start;
  background-color: darkgreen;
  max-height: 39rem;
}

img {
  height: 7.3rem;
  width: 5rem;
}

.imgDrag {
  z-index: 1;
  opacity: 0.5;
}
```

```html
<link src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/themes/redmond/jquery-ui.css">
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>

<div id='top'> </div>
<h1> <b>BLACK JACK</b> </h1>
<div id='buttons'>
  <button type='button' id='startGame' class='btn btn-secondary'>Start game</button>
  <button type='button' id='shuffleCards' class='btn btn-secondary hidden'>mix cards</button>
  <button type='button' id='enough' class='btn btn-secondary'>Enough</button>
</div>
<div id='index'></div>
<div id='gameDesk'></div>
<div id='cardsDesk'></div>
<div id="hold-stuff">
  <span class='slot hidden'>drag card here</span>
</div>
```

Comment: thank you very much for your help, maybe not quite what I needed, but ( maybe I asked the question incorrectly myself).. I mention good ones are in the answer and I will be able to move on.. I am still just starting out,so every correction tip is very important.. thank you very much again

Comment: @DarŽuk  Glad this was able to help you, a good bit of this was out of scope of the question (unclosed tags in script like `<div id='top' </div>` - I prefer to put elements/tags in the HTML rather than script as it is easier to maintain and notice this in development tools.  The simplest possible example to reproduce your issue will help you in future questoins.

Comment: With CSS I often go with "it works, now what can I remove that still does but makes it simpler or not as much used"